# Does Google Cloud Vision API support face recognition or face identification?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am looking for a Google Cloud API that can do both face recognition and identification. My understanding is that the Google Cloud Vision API will support only face detection, but not recognition.

Is there any Google Cloud API that can do face recognition?

Comment: I'm afraid resource requests are not on topic on Stack Overflow - but if Google offers such a service, if there's nothing when searching for `Google Face Recognition API`, it probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Short answer: No. 
Google Cloud has chosen not to offer general-purpose facial recognition APIs before working through important technology and policy questions.
https://www.blog.google/around-the-globe/google-asia/ai-social-good-asia-pacific/

Answer (score 4):

Cloud Vision currently supports face *detection*, but not face *recognition*.

That is, it can tell you whether or not there are faces in an image (and where they all are), but it **cannot** tell you *which* faces are in the image.

Answer (score 3):

According to Google Vision API documentation. It doesn't support Face Recognition, only Face Detection and other attributes detection such as lable, landmark, web, label.

**Face Detection** : detect multiple faces within an image, along with the associated key facial attributes like emotional state or wearing headwear. ***Facial Recognition is not supported.***

**Label Detection** :  Detect broad sets of categories within an image, ranging from modes of transportation to animals.

**Explicit Content Detection** : Detect explicit content like adult content or violent content within an image.

**Logo Detection** : Detect popular product logos within an image.

**Landmark Detectio**n : Detect popular natural and man-made structures within an image.

**Image Attributes** : Detect general attributes of the image, such as dominant colors and appropriate crop hints.
Web Detection :  Search the Internet for similar images.

**Optical Character Recognition** : Detect and extract text within an image, with support for a broad range of languages, along with support for automatic language identification.

Check out more details : https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Hope it can help you and more ideas and concepts

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Vision Api doesn't offer Face Recognition, only Face Detection and 4 emotions in the face detected, and 3 properties like blurred, underexposed and with hat.

You can use the OpenCv library (not Google product) to create your custom application with pretrained machine learning model.